# ScalaTest + ScalaCheck : Cannot find implicit Arbitrary[List[Integer]]

Tags: scala, implicit, scalatest, scalacheck

How can I compile this? Are there implicit generators for List[Int], how do I bring them in scope? 
I thought `import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary._` should suffice, but it does not.

```
package foo

import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite
import org.scalatest.prop.Checkers
import org.scalacheck._
import org.junit.Test


class TestFoo extends JUnitSuite with Checkers {

  @Test
  def foo : Unit = {
    def revtest(l: List[Integer]) : Boolean = l.reverse.reverse==l
    check(revtest _) //could not find implicit value for parameter a1: org.scalacheck.Arbitrary[List[Integer]]
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is pretty stupid. The code above refers `java.lang.Integer` instead of `Int`. Replacing with `Int` solves the issue.